# Will Cakephp 2.4.5 run with some core PHP functions disabled?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any way to run Cakephp 2.4.5 without the following core php functions?

```
pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wterm

sig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pc

ntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,getenv, php_uname, getmyuid, getmypid, passthru, leak, listen, 

diskfreespace, tmpfile, link, ignore_user_abord, shell_exec, dl, exec, system, highlight_file, source, show_source, fpaththru, 

virtual, posix_ctermid, posix_getcwd, posix_getegid, posix_geteuid, posix_getgid, posix_getgrgid, posix_getgrnam, 

posix_getgroups, posix_getlogin, posix_getpgid, posix_getpgrp, posix_getpid,posix, _getppid, posix_getpwnam, 

posix_getpwuid,posix_getrlimit, posix_getsid, posix_getuid,posix_isatty, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setegid,posix_seteuid, 

posix_setgid, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid,posix_setuid, posix_times, posix_ttyname, posix_uname,proc_open, proc_close, 

proc_get_status, proc_nice,proc_terminate, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, ini_alter, dl,popen, pcntl_exec, 

socket_accept,socket_bind, socket_clear_error, socket_close, socket_connect, 

pg_lo_import,dbmopen,dbase_open,chgrp,chown,chmod,symlink,apache_child_terminate,apache_setenv,define_syslog_variables,pclose,cu

rl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,gzinflate,apache_get_modules,mysql_get_client_info,ini_set,ftp_alloc,ftp_cdup,ftp_chdir,ftp_chmod,f

tp_close,ftp_connect,ftp_delete,ftp_exec,ftp_fget,ftp_fput,ftp_get_option,ftp_get,ftp_login,ftp_mdtm,ftp_mkdir,ftp_nb_continue,f

tp_nb_fget,ftp_nb_fput,ftp_nb_get,ftp_nb_put,ftp_nlist,ftp_pasv,ftp_put,ftp_pwd,ftp_quit,ftp_raw,ftp_rawlist,ftp_rename,ftp_rmdi

r,ftp_set_option,ftp_site,ftp_size,ftp_ssl_connect,ftp_systyp
```

Comment: Is this a restriction placed upon your hosting? The answer may be just to try it, but otherwise you could always change hosts.

Comment: I've trimmed the list down, since no-one is going to read it all, and it was not well-formatted anyway.

Comment: I recommend asking the developers directly.

Comment: Have to say I don't understand the close and downvotes; the asker could demonstrate more effort but the question is clear enough and _possibly_ useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

### Probably no problem

Of the functions listed only the following stands out as a function used on every rrquest:

- [getenv](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.5/lib/Cake/basics.php#L309)

Having `getenv` disabled is unlikely to have any affect on the functionality of the framework itself though (you may of course need to remove the call to it to prevent warnings showing).

The majority of the functions are not used anywhere, there are some in use such as [parse_ini_file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.5/lib/Cake/Configure/IniReader.php#L108), but not in core functionality; as such that functionality may not work, but it's not fundamentally required by the framework. To see exactly which of the functions in the list are in use - just search the source code =).

### However: Suck it and see

That's not to say that your/a-random application code will work - if it calls any functionality which is dependent on a disabled function (whether in the core or not) it will of course fail to work (correctly, or at all). Therefore the most appropriately response to the question as posed is:

> when you tried, *did it work*?